# utltsnips - surround with space

Tags: r, vim, ultisnips

I have the following utilsnips script that I use for Vim:

```
snippet - "assignment"
<-
endsnippet
```

I use it for R to expand a dash to the assignment operator. I would like to make it so that a space is put both before and after the `<-` on expansion. However, when I put a space before it in the snippet like `<-`, it won't expand on hitting `Tab`. How should I modify the script to have spaces around the operator? Desired result: `<-`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`r` option](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/f66f3d8b95e327178fcdaa58b4bc68098c15846f/doc/UltiSnips.txt#L697-L703) to include head and trailing spaces around snippets. `r` will treat snippet as a python regular expression and you should define your snippet within quotes when using this flag.

```
snippet " -" "assignment" r
 <- 
endsnippet
```

**Note** that there is a space before and after `<-` in snippet definition.

As a bonus, It's more interesting to define the snippet like the following:

```
snippet " - " "assignment" rA
 <- 
endsnippet
```

`A` is autoexpansion. so now you dont need to hit `tab` anymore! just type `-` and as soon as you type *space* after `-` it will expand to `<-` **Automatically**.